# PHP Variable in HTML page

Tags: php, html, variables, post

Can i add variables to an HTML page ?

Example:

I have this:

```
<form action="[FORUM_LOGIN_URL/]" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" id="loginForm" method="post" name="loginForm" onsubmit="return handleLogin();">
  <div id="loginFormContainer">
    <input id="loginField" name="login" type="hidden" value="login"> 
    <input id="redirectField" name="redirect" type="hidden" value="[REDIRECT_URL/]">
    <div>
      <label for="userNameField">[LANG]userName[/LANG]:</label><br>
      <input id="userNameField" maxlength="[USER_NAME_MAX_LENGTH/]" name="username" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="Liel">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="passwordField">אין צורך בסיסמה:</label><br>
      <input id="passwordField" name="password" readonly="readonly" type="password">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="languageSelection">[LANG]language[/LANG]:</label><br>
      <select id="languageSelection" name="lang" onchange="ajaxChat.switchLanguage(this.value);">
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input id="loginButton" name="submit" type="submit" value="[LANG]login[/LANG]">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I need a variable in the value:

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="!variable!" name="username" id="userNameField" maxlength="[USER_NAME_MAX_LENGTH/]"/></div>
```

I have also the lang.php and if i can add variable in lang line:

```
$lang['langexample'] = 'variable';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add php code in html with php tag. For example

```
<?php echo $something; ?>
```

Before that you need to make sure, you file have to save as ".php" extension.

Comment: I think there is no other way excerpt from using AJAX or template engines

Comment: ok thank you, 
and in Lang.php i can add variable ?
its php but have '' and i cant add my variable into it.